# Exception org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException caused but i don't know why

Tags: spring

i am new in spring . and i learn but during learning i get error.
i use XML based configuration for spring and here are compilation error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'helloGeorgia' defined in class path resource [Beans.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'werili' of bean class [com.tutorialspoint.HelloGeorgia]: Bean property 'werili' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

but i can not understand why .

here are bean.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans  xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="helloworld" class="com.tutorialspoint.HelloWorld">
        <property name="message" value = "Hello World" />
        <property name="werili" value = "Hello Hello" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="helloGeorgia" class="com.tutorialspoint.HelloGeorgia" 
             parent="helloworld">
        <property name="message" value="Hello Georgia" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

and here are the three java files :
**MainApp.java**

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;



public class MainApp {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");

        HelloWorld f = (HelloWorld) context.getBean("helloworld");
        System.out.println(f.getMessage());

        HelloGeorgia georgia = (HelloGeorgia) context.getBean("helloGeorgia");
        System.out.println(georgia.getMessage());

    }
}
```

**HelloWorld.java**

```
package com.tutorialspoint;


public class HelloWorld {
    private String message;
    private String werili;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getWerili() {
        return werili;
    }

    public void setWerili(String werili) {
        this.werili = werili;
    }
}
```

**HelloGeorgia.java**

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

public class HelloGeorgia {
    private String message;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;

    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

}
```

please advise me how to fix it . Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look at your spring configuration helloGeorgia is expected to be child of helloWorld bean. Where as in java class that is not the case. Either you should have inheritance in java also or, atleast; you should declare same fields with getter/setter in helloGeorgia.